# Store sql query output and send it in email to DL or particular email ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I want to run sql query from a .bat file. I understand how to create a .bat file and .sql file and then call .sql file from the .bat file. My question is how can I store its output under any location and then send it over to email.

My current .bat looks like

```
osql -S <ServerName> -U <User Name> -P <Password> < mysqlfile.sql
```

...And my .sql file runs the below query

```
select * from sysssislog where event='onerror' order by starttime desc
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What version of sql server?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up SQL Server 2008 Database mail as shown [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

Then, you can Email the results of a query as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658780/passing-stored-procedure-to-sp-send-dbmail)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) or a VBscript to do it.

```
osql -S <ServerName> -U <User Name> -P <Password> -o Out.txt < mysqlfile.sql
Blat out.txt -to <recipient> -s <subject> -server <ip or hostname of SMTP server:<port>
```

Here is a Batch file that creates a VBScript to do it.

```
@echo off
setlocal

if exist "out.txt" del "out.txt"
osql -S Server -U user -P password -o Out.txt < mysqlfile.sql
set vbs_=Email.vbs
set skip=
findstr "'%skip%VBS" "%~f0" > "%vbs_%"
cscript //nologo "%vbs_%"
ping -n 3 localhost>nul
if exist "%vbs_%" del "%vbs_%"
goto :eof

 Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2                      'VBS
 sFile="Out.txt"                                           'VBS
 Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     'VBS
 Set oFile = oFso.OpenTextFile(sFile, ForReading)          'VBS
 Set oMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")                     'VBS
 sSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 'VBS
     with oMail.Configuration.Fields                       'VBS
     .Item(sSchema & "sendusing")= 2                   'VBS  
     .Item(sSchema & "smtpserver")= "YourServer"       'VBS
     .Item(sSchema & "smtpserverport") = 25              'VBS 
     .Update                                           'VBS                                              
     end with                                              'VBS 
 oMail.Subject="SQL Log"                                   'VBS
 oMail.From="email@domain.com"                             'VBS
 oMail.To="Sendto@someother.com"                           'VBS
 oMail.TextBody = oFile.ReadAll                            'VBS 
 oMail.Send                                                'VBS
 oFile.Close                                               'VBS 
 set oMail=nothing                                         'VBS
 set oFile = Nothing                                       'VBS
```

Comment: Hi I ran the above batch file but it gave me below error, can you please be more specific on sSchema...Here is the error D:\Test\mail.vbs(7, 1) CDO.Message.1: The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.


The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\Program Files\CA\WA Agent R11.3.1\Email.vbs(4, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found

C:\Program Files\CA\WA Agent R11.3.1\Email.vbs(4, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found

Comment: Ok. What I'm gathering from this is that you first took the VBS code only and created MAIL.VBS and tested it. That returned the error about the SendUsing config value is invalid. A value of 2 for SendUsing means to send using a port. Are you sure your SMTP server is listening on port 25? Try to Telnet to it using `Telnet your.smtp.server 25` and see if it responds with a 220. If not, Telnet to your server using port 443 and see if it responds. If it responds on 443 but not 25, we have to tweak the code a bit to use SSL

Comment: After you did that, you created the Batch file in the C:\Program Files\CA\WA Agent R11.3.1 directory and ran it, which gave the File Not Found error. This would happen if the out.txt file was never created. Did you create a file called mysqlfile.sql with your T-SQL query in it and put it in the same directory? That or change the name of the .sql file in the batch to match yours? If you didn't do that, it won't work.